# Matching Well data to Precip data, but getting error argument length of 0

Tags: r

Using sample data: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIwos.png) and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1caza.png)

Precipitation events

```
eventid precipitation   eventStart  eventEnd
1   2   2015-05-18  2015-05-18
3   6   2015-05-25  2015-05-25
5   2   2015-05-29  2015-05-29
```

Well level data

```
Date    Level
2015-05-18  0.012
2015-05-19  0.017
2015-05-20  0.016
2015-05-21  0.015
2015-05-22  0.007
2015-05-23  0.002
2015-05-24  -0.002
2015-05-25  0.006
2015-05-26  0.017
2015-05-27  0.014
2015-05-28  0.01
2015-05-29  0.009
2015-05-30  0.005
```

trying to get the corresponding well data to match the precipitation data

```
well_data$Date <- as.POSIXct(well_data$Date, format("%Y/%m/%d"))
rainfall_event_data$Start <- as.POSIXct(rainfall_event_data$eventStart, format("%Y/%m/%d"))
rainfall_event_data$End <- as.POSIXct(rainfall_event_data$eventEnd, format("%Y/%m/%d"))

rainfall_event_data$Start <- rainfall_event_data$Start - 7*60

event_check_range <- 2*24 
na_counter <- 0w

well_timestamp <- "Date"
well_data_name <- "DWL2015"
rainfall_timestamp <- "eventStart"

extraced_data <- data.frame("rise_start_timestamp", "rise_start_value", "peak_timestamp", "Peak_value", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
complete_extracted_data <- data.frame()
for(rainfall_index in 1:nrow(rainfall_event_data)){
  #Find the index in the well data for which the rainfall event corresponds
  rainfall_event_start <- rainfall_event_data[rainfall_index, rainfall_timestamp]
  start_index <- which (well_data[[well_timestamp]] == rainfall_event_start)
  end_index <- start_index + event_check_range
  
  
  for (well_data_index in start_index:end_index){
    previous_well_data <- well_data[well_data_index - 1, well_data_name]
    current_well_data <- well_data[well_data_index, well_data_name]
    next_well_data <- well_data[well_data_index + 1, well_data_name]
```

'Error in start_index:end_index : argument of length 0'

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)